# Find closest element downward based on anoter clicked element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic form, that can add new row, delete row. Here's the code:

```
// HTML
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
      <li><input class="landmark" type="checkbox" value="4" name="patient[block_procedure_part2_notes_attributes][0][monitoring_device_ids][]" id="patient_block_procedure_part2_notes_attributes_0_monitoring_device_ids_4" /></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
      <li><input class="us_image" type="radio" value="clear" checked="checked" name="patient[block_procedure_part2_notes_attributes][0][us_image]" id="patient_block_procedure_part2_notes_attributes_0_us_image_clear" /></li>
      <li><input class="us_image" type="radio" value="clear" checked="checked" name="patient[block_procedure_part2_notes_attributes][0][us_image]" id="patient_block_procedure_part2_notes_attributes_0_us_image_poor" /></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
      <li><input class="landmark" type="checkbox" value="4" name="patient[block_procedure_part2_notes_attributes][1][monitoring_device_ids][]" id="patient_block_procedure_part2_notes_attributes_1_monitoring_device_ids_4" /></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
      <li><input class="us_image" type="radio" value="clear" checked="checked" name="patient[block_procedure_part2_notes_attributes][1][us_image]" id="patient_block_procedure_part2_notes_attributes_1_us_image_clear" /></li>
      <li><input class="us_image" type="radio" value="clear" checked="checked" name="patient[block_procedure_part2_notes_attributes][1][us_image]" id="patient_block_procedure_part2_notes_attributes_1_us_image_poor" /></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

// Javascript
var landmark = $('input.landmark');

landmark.change(function(event) {
  var usImageOptions = $(event.target).closest('input.us_image');
  if (landmark.prop('checked')) {
    resetInputs(usImageOptions);
    controlFormSub();
    disableInputs(usImageOptions, true);
  } else {
    disableInputs(usImageOptions, false);
  }
});
```

You can see that there are 2 `.row`s. More rows could be added with an add button, or remove with a remove button.

Here I am trying to disable the `usImageOptions` radio buttons, corresponding to the nearest `.landmark` that is checked. If `.landmark` in 1st `.row` is checked, then the 1st `.row`'s `.usImageOptions` should be cleared and disabled. The 2nd `.row` should be intact.

I'm reluctant to find by other classes because if they changed, then this code would break.

I've tried numerous ways to select the `.usImageOptions` within same row but couldn't. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using:

```
var usImageOptions = $(event.target).closest('.row').find('.us_image');
```

This will first detect the clicked element, then look for the closest `.row` (though there are many, but it will select only the closest above), then look for the `.us_image` within that found `.row`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can grab the `.row` parent, and select your radio buttons from there:

```
$('.landmark').on('change', function(e){
    $(this).parents('.row').find('.us_image').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

EDIT: Since you're adding more rows, you'll likely need to use event delegation so that you can catch any rows that were added.

```
$(document.body).on('change', '.landmark', function(e){
    $(this).parents('.row').find('.us_image').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: Can I do without relying other classes? Because if the markup change, then this script would break.

Comment: Sure. You could always select based on `:checkbox` and `:radio`, ignoring classes completely. As long as you know how to get to their comment ancestor node, you'll be fine. You could even use `.parent().parent().parent().parent()` to navigate from `LI` to `UL` to `DIV` to `DIV` in the example above.

Comment: Because each part also has .row, it includes all 4 .usImageOptions when I find it. But I just want the nearest 2 within the same .row.